# Random Binary Search Tree, expected value of nodes with two children

Tags: probability-theory, trees, random-graphs

In class, the professor showed that using a uniform random permutation $$ X_1,..., X_n$$ (each being i.i.d.) we can construct a Binary Search Tree by inserting the values in to the tree by their indices. That is fairly straightforward. We can right it as pairs: 
$$ {(X_1, 1), .., (X_n, n)} $$

We can now define the inverse permutation as: 
$$ {(1, Y_1), .., (n, Y_n)} $$

I understand it as given as a pair with the Global Rank of some node and a random variable representing the time that this node is inserted. I understand how this shows that any two consecutive values

$$ {(i, Y_i), (i+1, Y_{i+1})} $$

are in an ancestor-descendant relationship. This means that i is a leaf if

$$ Y_i = max(Y_{i-1}, Y_i, Y_{i+1}) $$

Thus, apart from rank 1 and rank n, the probability that any node is a leaf is 1/3 and 1/2 otherwise. This yields the expected number of leaves to be:

$$ E_{\# leaves} = \frac{1}{2} + \sum_{i=2}^{n-1}{1/3} + \frac{1}{2} = \frac{n+1}{3}$$

Ok, I'm good to this point. But then he makes a statement that the expected number of nodes with two children are one less then the above, that is  they are
$$ \frac{n-2}{3} $$ This would make the expected number of nodes with only one child:  $$ \frac{n+1}{3} $$

**I do not understand why the expected number of nodes with two children is one less then the expected number of leaves?**

Answer (score 1):

The property holds for the binary tree with one node (which has 0 node with two children and 1 leave) and, each time one adds two children to a leave of a binary tree such that the property holds, it still holds for the larger tree (which has 1 more leave and 1 more node with two children), QED.